# How to delete everything that contains ".com" in the string but has a link?

Tags: r, string, gsub

How can I get the output I expected in texts like the example below?

```
x<-c("Commerce recommend erkanexample.com.tr. This site erkanexample.com. erkandeneme.com is widely. The company name is apple.commerce is coma. spread")
x<-gsub("(.com)\\S+", "",x)
x
[1] "Commerce r erkanexample This site erkanexample erkandeneme.com is widely. The name is apple is"
expected
[1] "Commerce recommend This site. is widely. The company name is apple.commerce is coma. spread"
>
```

Comment: Try `x<-gsub("\\s*\\S+\\.com\\b(?:\\.\\S+)?", "", x)`

Comment: Try `gsub("\\s*\\S+\\.com(?:\\.\\w+)*\\b", "", x)` if the above does not work.

Comment: Does any of the solutions work?

Comment: Thank you very much @Wiktor Stribiżew  and everyone. Both seem to work. I would like you to give me some time to fully check the database I have.

Comment: Codes are works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
gsub("\\s[a-z]+\\.com(\\.[a-z]+)?\\b", "", x)
[1] "Commerce recommend. This site. is widely. The company name is apple.commerce is coma. spread"
```

Here, we replace by nothing:

- `\\s`: one white space character
- `[a-z]+`: one or more lower-case letters
- `\\.`: one period
- `com`: the string `com`
- `(\\.[a-z]+)?`: an optional period followed by one or more optional lower-case letters
- `\\b`: a word boundary

Comment: Thank you @Chris Ruehlemann . Your answer seems to be working. I would like you to give me some time to fully check the database I have.

Answer (score 0):

`stringr` package provides functions for basic string manipulation:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
  str_split(" ") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  str_subset("\\.com($|\\.)",negate = TRUE) %>% 
  str_c(collapse = " ")
```

gives:

```
"Commerce recommend This site is widely. The company name is apple.commerce is coma. spread"
```

**AFTER EDIT**

```
x %>% 
  str_split(" ") %>% 
  unlist() %>%
  str_subset("\\.com$", negate = TRUE) %>% 
  str_replace(".*\\.com.*\\.$", ".") %>%
  str_c(collapse = " ") %>%
  str_replace_all(" \\.", "\\.")
```

gives:

```
"Commerce recommend. This site. is widely. The company name is apple.commerce is coma. spread"
```

Comment: Thank you @det  I corrected an error while manually writing the expected output. "... This site." I forgot the dot sign here. I'm trying. I will give information.

Comment: I've added edit but i'm not sure if it is what you want.

Comment: The output I expected was correct. It was simpler to do with Gsub, and I had a lot of solutions. I do checks on my database. It worked in your answer. I was surprised which one to choose. Thanks @det .

Comment: @Erkan Yeah sure no problem glad to help. I'm not so good with regex.

Answer (score 0):

IDEA: Split  by space and detect which word contains the .com and select which does not contain that and join them

```
x<-c("Commerce recommend erkanexample.com.tr. This site erkanexample.com. erkandeneme.com is widely. The company name is apple.commerce is coma. spread")
split_str <- str_split(x," ",simplify =FALSE)[[1]]
paste(split_str[!grepl("[.]com", split_str)],collapse = " ")
```

gives

"Commerce recommend This site is widely. The company name is is coma. spread"

Comment: updated the answer as regex require to detect `.com` is `'[.]com'`

Comment: Thank you @vishal . Solutions written in gsub seem simpler to me. They seem to be working. I would like you to give me some time to fully check the database I have.